# Type Error: Keyword Argument 'solc_version'

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, compiler

I received the following error while trying to execute a custom built web3.py

```
install_solc("0.6.0")
complied_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
solc_wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'solc_version'
```

If anyone knows how to fix this. Kindly Help Out. Is this deprecated and is there a new-way or using it?
Note: I am using 0.6.0 version of Solidity.

Comment: Is `evm.sourceMap` working? What about  `evm.bytecode.sourceMap`?

Comment: @v1bio How do I know mate? How do I Check It??

Comment: change the code

Comment: I did, doesn't seem to fix the error. Even changing the solc version doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a day and some coffee but fixed it. I am not completely sure how I got it working but here is a list of troubleshooting steps I was trying that helped me out.

- Uninstall py-solc-x via terminal using, `pip uninstall py-solc-x`
- Use `pip cache purge` to remove any redundant packages. (Optional)
- Recheck the path `lib\site-packages\solcx\bin\` in your python installation folder [or your virtual environment]. If there is something inside it. Delete It. (If it doesn't exist, then skip)
- Reinstall py-solc-x via `pip install py-solc-x`.
- Check your `Solidity Global Compiler Version` in VSCode by hitting **Ctrl + Shift + P** and set it the one mentioned by you in your *install_solc()* and *solc_version* and *pragma solidity*.
- [For Virtual Environments Only] Check if you have any conflicting py-solc-x packages on your host python directory via `pip freeze`.
- Last but not least, Check If you the correct `Python Interpreter` selected in the same way by hitting **Ctrl + Shift + P** in which you decide to work on. This can be helpful if you are on a virtual environment.